# Not sure if this set theory proof attempt involving contradiction is valid

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have recently started studying set theory, so I wanted to try out some exercises to test my understanding. When I came across one of the questions, I have found it quite tricky to tackle, so I tried using proof by contradiction to try and prove it. However, I'm not sure if this proof that I came up with makes sense.

The question asked me the following:
Let $A,B,C \text{ and }D$ be four sets. $$\text{Prove that if } A \cup B \subseteq C \cup D, A \cap B = \emptyset \text{ and } C \subseteq A \text{, then } B \subseteq D.$$
To begin with, I assumed that $B \nsubseteq D$ (to make use of the proof by contradiction technique), and proceeded like so.

Assume $B \nsubseteq D$. Then, this means that there exists an $x \in B$ and $x \notin D$. However, since $A \cup B \subseteq C \cup D$, we can also assume that $(x \in A \text{ or } x\in B) \text{ and } (x \in C \text{ or } x\in D)$. So, this implies that $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$. Since $C \subseteq A$ is a given piece of information, then $x \in C \text{ and } x \in A$. So, $x \in A \cap C$, which means that $x \notin B$ and this implies that $x \in D$. This is a condradiction. Therefore it must be the case that $B \subseteq D$.
∎

Would this be a valid proof?

Comment: "then, this means that x∈B and x∉D."  Nitpick.  Then this means *there exists an $x$* so that $x \in B$ and $x \not \in D$.  You can't introduce terms without .... introducing them.

Comment: You seem to be willy-nilly assuming $x$ is some sets on whim.  You have to declare what $x$ is and stick to it. If $x \in B$ and $x \not \in D$ that *that* is your $x$.  You can't just switch to $x$ being an element of $A\cup B$ of $C\cup D$.

Comment: If $x \in B$ but $x \not \in D$ then *that* is your $x$.  So $x \in B$ so $x \in B\subset A\cup B\subset C\cup D$.  So $x\in C$ or $x \in D$ but as $x$ is *not* $D$ we have $x\in C$. ...etc.... DO you see the difference in what I am saying from what you are saying? So as $x \in C$.  But $C\sub A$ so $x \in A$.  And *this* $x \in B$.  So $x \in A\cap B$.  But $A\cap B =\emptyset$ so *that* is our contradiction.

Comment: Proof by contradiction is counter-productive here (as it so often is). You want to show $B \subseteq D$: so pick $b \in B$ and work forwards from the hypotheses to show that $b \in D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though proving this statement by contradiction is a good idea, your "proof" presented here, unfortunately, doesn't make sense. Let's walk through your work step-by-step until we hit the major mistake in it.

> Assume $B\not\subseteq D$.

Good start. I would wanna do a proof by contradiction too.

> Then, this means that $x\in B$ and $x\notin D$.

This is a bit of a problem. Which $x$? What is this $x$ that you're talking about? You never introduced any $x$ before. The correct statement here should be: "Then, this means that ***there exists some $x$ such that*** $x\in B$ and $x\notin D$."

> However, since $A\cup B\subseteq C\cup D$, we can also assume that $(x\in A \text{ or } x\in B) \text{ and } (x\in C \text{ or } x\in D)$. So, this implies that $x\in (A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D)$.

This is, technicaly speaking, not wrong, but it's too convoluted. And actually, the word *"assume"* is not appropriate here. We don't need to *assume* this, because we ***know*** this. Remember that by our choice of $x$ we ***know*** that $x\in B$, therefore $x\in A\cup B=(A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D)$, where the latter equality is true because it's given that $A\cup B\subseteq C\cup D$.

> Since $C\subseteq A$ is a given piece of information, then $x\in C$ and $x\in A$.

And this is the mistake that breaks your argument. It's true that, by definition of set inclusion, $C\subseteq A$ means that any element of $C$ also belongs to $A$. But calling this element "$x$" is a serious mistake, because earlier you assigned the name of $x$ to something else. By using the same name $x$ here again, you're effectively talking about *the same* element. So you're saying that *the same* $x$ that you mentioned before also belongs to $C$ and (as a consequence) to $A$. Not only is it a logical mistake in general, but in this problems this is actually impossible: you can't have the same $x$ to be in $B$ as stated above and in $A$ as stated here, because we're given that $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

From this point, unfortunately, the rest of the solution doesn't matter …

But you have the right ideas in your work that can be turned into a valid proof! Hint: to reach a contradiction, demonstrate that this $x$ is not in $C\cup D$.

Comment: Why would you want to do a proof by contradiction, when the forward proof is so much simpler?

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @Arthan Could you perhaps show how a direct proof can be used here?

Comment: @RobArthan: You're probably right. For whatever reason, proving this by contradiction was the first thought that came to my mind. And once I saw that it works, I didn't think much more about it. But on the second thought, I agree that this can be easily proven directly.

Comment: A direct proof would be to select a $x \in B$ and prove that $x \in D$. It's not hard. (if $x\in B$ then $x\not \in A\subset C$ but $x\in B\subset A\cup B$ so $x\in C\cup D$ but not in $C$ so in $D$.)  But there's nothing wrong with a proof by contradiction.  I don't know if the question was directed to zipirovich or Mmmmm... $\pi$ but I think in answering it's best to follow the OPs approach and guide what is needed.

Comment: @fleablood: I take your point about giving guidance as needed, but my point is that if you are asked to prove that (under some hypotheses) $X \subseteq Y$, then the best first step is to see what you can discover from the hypothesis that some element $x$ is in $X$, and not what you can discover from the logically more complicated statement  $\lnot X \subseteq Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting a proof draw a Venn diagram:

[image]

For a direct proof it helpful if you know some rules/laws so that you don't have to check whether each element of $B$ is in $D$ - you can operate at a higher level.

Now the Venn diagram doesn't include $D$, but somehow $C \cup D$ has to "cover" $A \cup B$. But $C$ is disjoint from $B$ so can't expect it to "cover" any of $B$. So it is all up to $D$ to "cover" $B$.

One approach is to let $U = A \cup B \cup C \cup D$ be the universal set.
Can you now get 'something going' with the complement $\overline C$ of the set $C$?

Answer (score 1):

An attenpt at showing graphically the logical structure of the proof by contradiction

[image]